# how to make a SELECT that merges duplicated Primary Keys

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I'm performing a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT a.transactionID,a.customerID,b.value      
        FROM adjustments a 
                INNER JOIN change b 
                        on  a.transactionID = b.transactionID 
                        and a.event_date    = b.event_date 
                        and a.event_id      = b.event_id 
        WHERE comment LIKE 'TRANSFER'
        ORDER BY a.transactionID;
```

this query brings the following result:

```
    transactionID | customerID | value
   ------------------------------------     
    TRANSFER-001  |    CUSTA   | -200
    TRANSFER-001  |    CUSTB   |  200
    TRANSFER-002  |    CUSTC   | -150
    TRANSFER-002  |    CUSTD   |   0
    TRANSFER-003  |    CUSTA   |   0
    TRANSFER-003  |    CUSTC   |  150
```

I need to change this query to bring a list that ignore those cases where the sum of `value` is **0** for the same `transactionID` and also, group the `customerID` and values as following:

```
   transactionID | customerID_A | value_A | customerID_B | value_B
 ------------------------------------------------------------------     
    TRANSFER-002 |    CUSTC     |   -150  |    CUSTD     |    0
    TRANSFER-003 |    CUSTA     |      0  |    CUSTC     |  150
```

Can you give any advise about how to solve this?

Comment: Can you show us what table A and B look like? It seems that you have columns in your desired output not mentioned in your original query

Comment: @kabball The admin doesn't allow me to share the full table properties, but I can say that the table A store all the tranfer details (time, date, user involved, service used, etc) an the table B, only store the ammount and some other numerical data.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this :**

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT a.transactionID,a.customerID,b.value      
    FROM adjustments a 
    INNER JOIN change b 
                    on  a.transactionID = b.transactionID 
                    and a.event_date    = b.event_date 
                    and a.event_id      = b.event_id 
    WHERE comment LIKE 'TRANSFER'
)M
GROUP BY transactionID,customerID,value
HAVING SUM(value) <> 0
ORDER BY transactionID;
```

Comment: I think SUM(value) <> 0 instead. He didn't say it couldn't be negative, just not 0

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT distinct a.transactionID,a.customerID,b.value      
    FROM adjustments a 
            INNER JOIN change b 
                    on  a.transactionID = b.transactionID 
                    and a.event_date    = b.event_date 
                    and a.event_id      = b.event_id 
    WHERE comment LIKE 'TRANSFER'
    ORDER BY a.transactionID;
```

Try distinct at the beginning it will eliminate all the duplicate values.

Comment: thanks dude i'll try all the suggestions! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want conditional aggregation.  However, you need to pivot the customers and there is no column for doing that.  You can enumerate the customers for each transaction using variables, and use that to pivot the first two customers on the transaction:

```
SELECT transactionId,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN customerId END) as customer_A,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN value END) as value_A,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN customerId END) as customer_B,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN value END) as value_B
FROM (SELECT a.transactionID, a.customerID, b.value,
             (@rn := if(@t = a.transactionID, @rn + 1,
                        if(@t := a.transactionID, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      FROM adjustments a INNER JOIN
           change c 
           ON a.transactionID = c.transactionID AND
              a.event_date    = c.event_date AND
              a.event_id      = c.event_id CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @t := '') params,
      WHERE comment LIKE 'TRANSFER'
      ORDER BY a.transactionID, b.value DESC
     ) t
GROUP BY transactionId
HAVING SUM(value) <> 0;
```

Comment: im experimenting around this, thanks for the help. I'll come back if I have any other question!